# How do I export multiple function calls in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, es6-modules, module.exports

I have this in my file:

```
 export default withAuth(authOptions)(ProfilePage);
```

But I also need to export this:

```
function mapStateToProps (state) {
  const { isLoggedIn } = state
  return { isLoggedIn}
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
  bindActionCreators({ logInUser }, dispatch)

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ProfilePage)
```

I can I combine them so they both work?

Comment: Why not this? export default withAuth(authOptions)(connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ProfilePage));

Comment: glad it helped! Here is why it works since in withAuth(authOptions)(SOME-COMPONENT) we need to provide component,also connect()() returns a component putting it inplace of SOME-COMPONENT solves our issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can using [`JS#named export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export).

```
export const  mapStateToProps =  (state)=> {
  const { isLoggedIn } = state
  return { isLoggedIn}
}
export const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>bindActionCreators({ logInUser }, dispatch)
```

now import it in other file

```
//test.js

import ProfilePage,{mapStateToProps ,mapDispatchToProps} from "path_to_file"
```